# "Value" not updated in JSF2-AJAX env

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

My environment : W7, Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2, Tomcat 6.0.35, jdk 1.7.02, jsf 2.0(Mojarra 2.03),JSTL 1.2.
Trying to implement a cascading dropdown for a more complex case, as a final trial  I wrote a VERY simple xhmtl that selects an item out of a selecOneMenu and puts immediately its content in an outputText by an f:ajax entry. The menu shows correctly, but, as I change the selection, nothing happens to the outputText. I can't figure out where is the mistake : wille you help me ?
Thanks.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"                                    
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">                                    

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"                                                        
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"                                                     
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"                                                          
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"                                                          
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">                                                             


  <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/BasicTemplate.xhtml">                                 
    <ui:define name="content">                                                                      
        <f:view>                                                                                      
        <h:form>                                                                                      
            <h:selectOneMenu id="firstDropDown" value="#{twoMenusBean.first}" style="width: 110px; ">   
                    <f:selectItems value="#{twoMenusBean.items}" />                                         
                    <f:ajax render="secondDropDown" immediate="true" ></f:ajax>                             
            </h:selectOneMenu>                                                                          


                <h:outputText id="secondDropDown" value="#{twoMenusBean.first}" ></h:outputText>          

            </h:form>                                                                                   
        </f:view>                                                                                     
    </ui:define>                                                                                    
  </ui:composition>                                                                                 
  </html>
```

The bean:

```
package myJava;




  @ManagedBean (name="twoMenusBean")                                   
  @SessionScoped                                                       

  public class twoMenusBean  {                                         

    private List<String> menu1List = new ArrayList<String>();          
    private String first;                                              

    public  twoMenusBean(){                                            

            menu1List.add("item 1");                                       
            menu1List.add("item 2");                                       
            first ="item 1";                                               
    }                                                                  
    public String getFirst(){                                          
        return first;                                                    
    }                                                                  
    public void setFirst(String first){                                
        this.first = first;                                              
    }                                                                  

    public List<SelectItem> getItems(){                                
        List<SelectItem> x = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();                
        for (int i = 0; i < menu1List.size() ;i++) {                     
            x.add(new SelectItem(menu1List.get(i),menu1List.get(i)));      
        }                                                                
        return x;                                                        
    }                                                                  
  }
```

Comment: are your `ManagedBean` and `SessionScoped` imports from `import javax.faces.bean....` ? does it work without `immediate="true"` ?

Comment: imports are : import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped.  No effect of "immediate": the behaviour is the same in any case.

Comment: take a look at the wiki tag http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info , follow the instructions over there... http://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info and remove the line `first ="item 1";`

Comment: Same result. I addeda line "<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --"></f:selectItem>" and deleted "first" initialization: the outpuText now results (?) in a blank line.

Comment: replace the `<f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="-- select one --"></f:selectItem>` with `<f:selectItem itemLabel="-- select one --" noSelectionOption="true"/>`

Comment: No chance. I tried the following:1) your  last advice (thanks...),  same environment; 2) new project (same sources,by drag and drop folder to folder) but jre 1.6.0.29,Tomcat 7; 3)this last env., sources according to your previous advice. In any case, Tomcat was restarted and trials were performed both with internal(to Eclipse) brower, AND IE9 AND Firefox 14:  outputText always results  blank. Next trial: a complete reset of the Eclipse env . (WTP); then , please let me know an env. where all this work....

Comment: My God : found. I omitted the h:head after  f:view.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `immediate="true"`: it has the side effect of skipping field updates (`setFirst` won't be called).